# How to solve Sales by Match problem using c#?

Tags: c#

I have challenge to solve Sales by Match problem using c# without use List collection ?

*Alex works at a clothing store. There is a large pile of socks that must be paired by color for sale. Given an array of integers representing the color of each sock, determine how many pairs of socks with matching colors there are.

For example, there are N =7 socks with colors ar=[1,2,1,2,1,3,2] There is one pair of color 1 and one of color 2. There are three odd socks left, one of each color. The number of pairs is 2 .*

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. We are not here to do your homework. To help with it yes, but not completly do it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
   static int sockMerchant(int n, int[] ar) {
    int matchingPairsCount= 0 ; 
     int[] arr =new int[n];
     var ix=0;
for (int i = 0 ; i< ar.Length ; i++)
{
     int countPairs = 0 ;
  for(int j = 0 ;j< ar.Length ;j++)
  {
     
      if(ar[i] == ar[j] && i<j&& (!arr.Contains(i)|| i==0))
      {
          arr[ix]=j;
          ix++;
            matchingPairs = matchingPairs + 1 ;
            break;
      }
  }

}
return  matchingPairsCount;
}
```

Comment: it's work fine Thank you Jassar

Comment: It's quite an expensive algorithm :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use it using the following code

```
var ar = new int[] { 1,2,1,2,1,3,2 };
ar.GroupBy( g => g ).Sum( g => Math.Floor( g.Count() / 2.0 ) );
```

It groups all the items in the array first, and then sums up all pairs. You can try it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vItiIz)

Comment: It works but I can't use Grouping

Comment: @Mark, maybe a `Dictionary` then?